# PHP - upload.class image and $_FILES

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm using [class.upload.php](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) to upload pictures onto the server. Here is my form:

```
<form action="<?="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table style="width: 100%; padding-top: 20px;">
    <tr>
        <td>Image file:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image_file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="add_new" value="Add image" /><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

In php code I do:

```
if( array_key_exists('add_new', $_POST) )
{
    echo 'add new is in array';

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo '</pre>';

    $handle = new Upload($_FILES['image_file']);
    ...
}
```

Here is an output of print_r:

```
Array
(
    [image_file] => somefile.png
    [add_new] => Add image
)
Array
(
)
```

As you can see second array is empty ($_FILES), so image doesn't upload. Why?

---

- operating system : Linux
- PHP version : 5.2.12
- GD version : 2.0.34
- supported image types : png jpg gif bmp
- open_basedir : /home/httpd/vhosts/%site%/httpdocs:/tmp

Comment: Strange. What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: @Pekka, I've just updated post.

Comment: Is the file being uploaded? Can you see that from the loading time on a big file?

Comment: @Pekka, nope. The page loads very fast.

Comment: @Ockonal is this with all browsers?

Comment: Check if `file_uploads` in php.ini is On

Comment: @Pekka, yeah, all browsers I tested. @dev-null-dweller I can't do this for now cause I haven't access for such things.

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, but the form looks fine and should at least send the file along. You don't happen to have another `form` element in the page that doesn't get properly closed?

Comment: try `var_dump(ini_get('file_uploads'));` to get this info

Comment: @dev-null-dweller string(1) "1". @Pekka this code works before. But I touched it again after several month on another host and now it doesn't work. There is another form in code file, but showable is only one of time in one time.

Comment: @Ockonal can you try removing that other form just to eliminate the possibility?

Comment: @Pekka I've checked all tags to be closing. And also updated the first version of this file which correctly worked before.

Comment: @Ockonal can you strip down a page to build a minimal test case, just to contain `body` and `form` and `input` elements?

Comment: @Pekka, I think it doesn't matter. I take code from start version which works on another my web-projects perfectly, but here doesn't want. I think, it's not a code problem.

Comment: @Ockonal probably, but I would still do it just to eliminate the possibility - you never know. If the file is not transferred to the server at all, I think it might be a problem with the form, maybe caused by something on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with images smaller than the post_max_size ini setting? Also, make sure your /tmp has space and is writable.

Other resources:

1) Long list of causes here: http://getluky.net/2004/10/04/apachephp-_files-array-mysteriously-empty/

2) From http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

```
As said before if POST size exceeds server limit then $_POST and $_FILES arrays become empty. You can track this using $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'].
For example:

<?php
$POST_MAX_SIZE = ini_get('post_max_size');
$mul = substr($POST_MAX_SIZE, -1);
$mul = ($mul == 'M' ? 1048576 : ($mul == 'K' ? 1024 : ($mul == 'G' ? 1073741824 : 1)));
if ($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > $mul*(int)$POST_MAX_SIZE && $POST_MAX_SIZE) $error = true;
?>
```

Comment: I saw that list, checked everything. The limit is 15M. I'm uploading 120 kb.

Comment: And /tmp status (or wherever the temp file gets saved)?